# Connect Cadence to Azure Cosmo Cassandra API

Tags: cassandra, cadence, cadence-workflow, temporal-workflow, azure-cosmosdb-cassandra-api

I am running cadence with cassandra externally running using docker run -e CASSANDRA_SEEDS=10.x.x.x e ubercadence/server:. and its running sucessfully.

Azure cosmos says, any system running on Cassandra can use Azure cosmos using provided cosmos cassandra APi, by modifying the client connection creation code, for example : GO app sample code :

```
func GetSession(cosmosCassandraContactPoint, cosmosCassandraPort, cosmosCassandraUser, cosmosCassandraPassword string) *gocql.Session {
    clusterConfig := gocql.NewCluster(cosmosCassandraContactPoint)
    port, err := strconv.Atoi(cosmosCassandraPort)
    
    clusterConfig.Authenticator = gocql.PasswordAuthenticator{Username: cosmosCassandraUser, Password: cosmosCassandraPassword}
    clusterConfig.Port = port
    clusterConfig.SslOpts = &gocql.SslOptions{Config: &tls.Config{MinVersion: tls.VersionTLS12}}
    clusterConfig.ProtoVersion = 4
    
    session, err := clusterConfig.CreateSession()
    ...
    return session
}
```

From my end, I can connect external cassandra's cqlsh(which cadence is using for persisting)  to azure cosmos and can create KeySpace, table in azure cosmo db.
However, when I run Cadence server, all new tables are still created on local cassandra itself(instead of Axure cosmos) might be, cadence is connected to cassandra only.

So there are basically 2 question shared below  :

1.Since cadence is written in GO, can we modify the source code to establish connection to AzureCosmoDb.
or

2. or can we pass the cosmocassandra's host, port, username, password, while running the cassandra and cadence separately (docker run -e CASSANDRA_SEEDS=10.x.x.x e ubercadence/server:)

cosmosCassandraContactPoint : xyz.cassandra.cosmos.azure.com
cosmosCassandraPort : 10350
cosmosCassandraUser : xyz
cosmosCassandraPassword : xyz

Answer (score 0):

I am actively working on supporting other NoSQL DBs: https://github.com/uber/cadence/issues/3514 it will be easier to use Azure cosmos/AWS Keyspace after that's done.

Basically we will just need to customize a small part from the existing Cassandra model.